If A and C are nearer, is B nearer too?
Let $A, B, C$ be three colinear points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $P, Q$ any two points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (on the same line or not). I am trying to prove (or disprove) the following lemma, where $d$ is some metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$:

If both $A$ and $C$ are nearer to $P$ than to $Q$, then the same holds for the middle point $B$:
($d(A,P) \leq d(A,Q)$ and $d(C,P) \leq d(C,Q)$) implies $d(B,P) \leq d(B,Q)$.

This is illustrated below, where all of $A, B$ and $C$ are nearer to $P$ than to $Q$.
]1
QUESTION:

Is the lemma true for any metric?
If not, is it true for all $\ell_p$ metrics?
If not, is it true at least for $\ell_1$ or $\ell_2$ metrics?

EDIT: the claim is not true for $\ell^1$ metric; here is the example from Theo Bendit's answer:


What do you mean by a "line", or indeed one point being "between" another point in a general metric space? Are you referring to $B$ being on the metric line segment between $A$ and $C$, i.e. $d(A, C) = d(A, B) + d(B, A)$? (Note: this contains, but does not coincide with, a line segment in a general normed linear space.)

@TheoBendit I meant that all points are in an Euclidean space, and the line is just an Euclidean line.

"I meant that all points are in an Euclidean space, and the line is just an Euclidean line."  But you asked about other metrics.  What does a line mean in an other metric.

Are you, perhaps, considering an arbitrary finite-dimensional real normed linear space instead?

@fleablood I edited the question to clarify. The points are in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and they are on the same "line" in the usual, geometric meaning of a line (in Euclidean geometry). The different metric $d$ is used only to compute the distances between the points.

@TheoBendit yes. Even more specifically, I am interested in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

It is certainly not true for every metric. It's not difficult to come up with counterexamples of the form $d(x, y) = \|f(x) - f(y)\|_2$, where $f : \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n$ is a bijection. Essentially, $f$ allows us to rearrange most subsets of $\Bbb{R}^n$ into a line segment, so the line becomes irrelevant.
As pointed out in the comments, you're more interested in norms anyway. This is still false, even under the $\ell^1$ norm. Take, for example, $A = (-1, -1)$, $B = (0, 0)$, $C = (1, 1)$, $P = (0, 0)$ and $Q = (1, -1)$. Then,
\begin{align*}
d(A, P) &= 2 \ge 2 = d(A, Q) \\
d(C, P) &= 2 \ge 2 = d(C, Q) \\
d(B, P) &= 0 < 2 = d(B, Q).
\end{align*}
Under the $\ell^2$ norm (or, more generally, with an inner product), the result does hold true. Note that, for a given point $P$, $\|A - P\| \ge \|A - Q\|$ is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
0 &\le \|P - A\|^2 - \|Q - A\|^2 \\
&= \langle (P - A) + (Q - A), (P - A) - (Q - A) \rangle \\
&= \langle P + Q - 2A, P - Q \rangle.
\end{align*}
Thus, we similarly have
$$\langle P + Q - 2C, P - Q \rangle \ge 0.$$
Since $B$ lies on the line segment between $A$ and $C$, there exists some $\lambda \in [0, 1]$ such that
$$B = \lambda A + (1 - \lambda) C,$$
hence
$$\langle P + Q - 2B, P - Q \rangle = \lambda \langle P + Q - 2A, P - Q \rangle + (1 - \lambda) \langle P + Q - 2C, P - Q \rangle \ge 0.$$
Thus, $\|P - B\|^2 - \|Q - B\|^2 \ge 0$, i.e. $d(P, B) \ge d(Q, B)$, as required.

Thanks! What about $\ell_p$ metrics for $p>1$?
